# Why poppler pdf rendering so bad in my program (Qt4)?

Tags: image, pdf, qt4, antialiasing, poppler

I am experimenting with poppler pdf library and `Qt4`.
I use this instruction:

```
image = pdfPage->->renderToImage(72.0,72.0, 
                                 0,0,
                                 pdfPage->pageSize().width(),
                                 pdfPage->pageSize().height());
```

Are there better parameters? Even if I put `200.0,200.0` quality is bad, compared to pdf reader in `Ubuntu`.

Comment: with no answers accepted so far, out of 11 total questions, probably noone will bother to look at it. You make a bad SO citizen. Feel ashamed :D

Comment: I click on "yes" at "Was this post useful to you?" button, I do not see other buttons. You feel ashamed not understanding this is a qui-pro-quo and you missed the occasion to help.

Comment: "quid-pro-quo", and what do you give in return, so far? Huh! You contradict yourself with your own arguments.

Comment: The operative word is 'Accept'

Comment: Maybe the fact that I do not log-in make this button not appear. However qui-pro-quo is synonym for "misunderstanding", while quid-pro-quo is synonym for "do-ut-des" (maybe I am asking too much to you @Flavius here) so I did not mean "do-ut-des" like you misunderstood, I correctly meant "misunderstand".

Comment: Yes P5music, maybe you are too good for us. I don't see any big interest of anyone to answer your question, so my first assumption still holds. Yet I am the one who hasn't understood SO. Haha. The point is, your own ego stays in the way of getting things right, for your own good. Unprofessional. Grow up. Cheers.

Comment: You stay professional too and avoid writing things like "Feel ashamed :D". I tell you again: I am not able or allowed to "accept" answers, probably because of not logging-in. Cheers.

Comment: You wouldn't be allowed to ask and post comments if you were not logged in. What kind of programmer are you?

Comment: Sure? Have you heard of cookies? This site allows users to post just with their nickname and email address. Stop bothering me or I will log-in and I will call for moderator's attention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

document->setRenderHint(Poppler::Document::TextAntialiasing);
was useful

Comment: Just to add to the answer, call setRenderHint() before renderToImage();

Comment: And since then, there are several new flags to render even better-looking, see [`RenderHint` enum documentation](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/api/qt6/classPoppler_1_1Document.html#a8420ce678235ee6214fbd91f5ae2f4e9)